# git connection timed out when cloning

Tags: github, connection

```
Installing https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cwrap-scm-1.rockspec...
Using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cwrap-scm-1.rockspec...
switching to 'build' mode
Cloning into 'cwrap'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Connection timed out
```

I am trying to install packages using git and it keeps on coming up with an error.
I cannot find anyone else with this problem so i thought i would ask

I was running a .sh file that installs all the dependencies needed for some code

https://github.com/kuz/DeepMind-Atari-Deep-Q-Learner/blob/master/install_dependencies.sh

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Looks like your device can't connect to github.com. Try to debug your network connection. Try `traceroute github.com` and show the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access the repository in question over the unauthenticated `git://` protocol, which you can see [in the rockspec file`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master/cwrap-scm-1.rockspec).  [GitHub dropped support for this protocol](https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/) because it's unencrypted and unsecured and is subject to arbitrary tampering.

You'll need to use a different protocol.  The easiest way is to update that URL such that it uses an HTTPS URL, which can be used anonymously but is secure (and which GitHub supports).  If you can't do that, you can run `git config url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`, which should automatically rewrite any URLs using the unauthenticated Git protocol on GitHub to their HTTPS version.

Comment: If you have been using GitHub for a long time, you may be using DSA based ssh public key which are deprecated by GitHub. Use RSA or ed25519 keys instead.

Comment: That would only apply to SSH, which would provide a different error message than the OP's.

Answer (score 1):

I found running the command
git config url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
didn't work
By replacing "git" with "https" in the "clone [https://github.com/..."](https://github.com/...%22) section of the command ran as expected and cloned the files into the required directory